# Upper bound for the remainder of Abel's test series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The aim is find an upper bound for $\left| \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k z_k \right|$, where $a_j$ is decreasing sequence of positive number and $\sum z_j$ converges.

Let $t_n$ be the partial sum of the series $\sum z_j$.  Then,
$$\begin{gathered}\left| \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_j z_j \right|&\leq& \sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_j z_j|\\&=&\sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_j(t_j-t_{j-1})|\\&\leq&a_n\sum_{k=n}^\infty |(t_j-t_{j-1})| \end{gathered}$$
Can we use $t_n$ is Cauchy here? But $n$ is fixed. Is there any other nice way to find an upper bound? Any help please

Comment: You lose the chance to get a bound by taking the absolute value sign inside the sum in the very first step.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ \sum\limits_{k=n}^{N}a_kz_k=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{N}a_k(t_k-t_{k-1})=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{N}(a_k-a_{k-1})t_k -a_nt_{n-1}$. Now use  a bound for $(t_i)$ and note that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{N}(a_k-a_{k-1})=a_N-a_{n-1}$

Comment: So the bound is $M(a-a_{n-1}  +a_n) $?

Comment: Simply $2Ma_n$?

Comment: $Ma_n$ is a bound, since $a_N -a_{n-1} \leq a_N \leq a_n$. @MadhanKumar